# How to match certain words between two strings (in MATLAB)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, match, words, stop-words

In the following two strings, the words 'rabbit' and 'tree' are matching:

```
str1 = ('rabbit is eating grass near a tree');
str2 = ('rabbit is sleeping under tree');
```

Suppose `cmp` is a variable declared to compare both. I want the result as:

```
cmp = 2
```

or something that shows that two words are matching.  How do I do this?

Comment: I suggest trying exploring MATLAB's string search/ comparison functions, taking a stab at the problem, and then coming back with some more concrete questions.

Comment: i want an integer value to be returned, if 3 words are matching in above strings, then want output as 3, as it will help me in performing if-else condition, which will help me in my future work

Comment: Shouldn't cmp be 3, as the word 'is' is also matching in the sample?

Comment: Yes it will be 3, but i will try to remove the stop-words

Comment: You would remove it yourself or MATLAB code has to? Because if MATLAB code has to, it would mean another pass with comparisons.

Comment: @Divakar Sir, I am trying to remove by MATLAB code.

Comment: @user3416063 have a look at my answer, there is a suggestion how to do that.

Comment: @Divakar Sir, any help regarding removal of stop words would be great.

Comment: @user3416063 Check out my answer with `bsxfun` approach too. Also, please edit your question with the stop-words requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Crazy" [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) approach, which might be similar to [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html), but not tested -

Function -

```
function out = cell2_matchind(split1,split2)

c1 = char(split1)-'0';
c2 = char(split2)-'0';
if size(c1,2)<size(c2,2)
    c1 = [c1 -16.*ones(size(c1,1),size(c2,2)-size(c1,2))];
else
    c2 = [c2 -16.*ones(size(c2,1),size(c1,2)-size(c2,2))];
end
out = any(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@eq,permute(c1,[3 2 1]),c2),2))==size(c2,2),2);
```

Main MATLAB script -

```
% Source of stopwords- http://norm.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/
stopwords_cellstring={'a', 'about', 'above', 'above', 'across', 'after', ...
    'afterwards', 'again', 'against', 'all', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', ...
    'already', 'also','although','always','am','among', 'amongst', 'amoungst', ...
    'amount',  'an', 'and', 'another', 'any','anyhow','anyone','anything','anyway', ...
    'anywhere', 'are', 'around', 'as',  'at', 'back','be','became', 'because','become',...
    'becomes', 'becoming', 'been', 'before', 'beforehand', 'behind', 'being', 'below',...
    'beside', 'besides', 'between', 'beyond', 'bill', 'both', 'bottom','but', 'by',...
    'call', 'can', 'cannot', 'cant', 'co', 'con', 'could', 'couldnt', 'cry', 'de',...
    'describe', 'detail', 'do', 'done', 'down', 'due', 'during', 'each', 'eg', 'eight',...
    'either', 'eleven','else', 'elsewhere', 'empty', 'enough', 'etc', 'even', 'ever', ...
    'every', 'everyone', 'everything', 'everywhere', 'except', 'few', 'fifteen', 'fify',...
    'fill', 'find', 'fire', 'first', 'five', 'for', 'former', 'formerly', 'forty', 'found',...
    'four', 'from', 'front', 'full', 'further', 'get', 'give', 'go', 'had', 'has', 'hasnt',...
    'have', 'he', 'hence', 'her', 'here', 'hereafter', 'hereby', 'herein', 'hereupon', ...
    'hers', 'herself', 'him', 'himself', 'his', 'how', 'however', 'hundred', 'ie', 'if',...
    'in', 'inc', 'indeed', 'interest', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'itself', 'keep', 'last',...
    'latter', 'latterly', 'least', 'less', 'ltd', 'made', 'many', 'may', 'me', 'meanwhile',...
    'might', 'mill', 'mine', 'more', 'moreover', 'most', 'mostly', 'move', 'much', 'must',...
    'my', 'myself', 'name', 'namely', 'neither', 'never', 'nevertheless', 'next', 'nine',...
    'no', 'nobody', 'none', 'noone', 'nor', 'not', 'nothing', 'now', 'nowhere', 'of', 'off',...
    'often', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'onto', 'or', 'other', 'others', 'otherwise',...
    'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'out', 'over', 'own','part', 'per', 'perhaps', 'please',...
    'put', 'rather', 're', 'same', 'see', 'seem', 'seemed', 'seeming', 'seems', 'serious',...
    'several', 'she', 'should', 'show', 'side', 'since', 'sincere', 'six', 'sixty', 'so',...
    'some', 'somehow', 'someone', 'something', 'sometime', 'sometimes', 'somewhere', ...
    'still', 'such', 'system', 'take', 'ten', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them',...
    'themselves', 'then', 'thence', 'there', 'thereafter', 'thereby', 'therefore', ...
    'therein', 'thereupon', 'these', 'they', 'thickv', 'thin', 'third', 'this', 'those',...
    'though', 'three', 'through', 'throughout', 'thru', 'thus', 'to', 'together', 'too',...
    'top', 'toward', 'towards', 'twelve', 'twenty', 'two', 'un', 'under', 'until', 'up',...
    'upon', 'us', 'very', 'via', 'was', 'we', 'well', 'were', 'what', 'whatever', 'when',...
    'whence', 'whenever', 'where', 'whereafter', 'whereas', 'whereby', 'wherein',...
    'whereupon', 'wherever', 'whether', 'which', 'while', 'whither', 'who', 'whoever',...
    'whole', 'whom', 'whose', 'why', 'will', 'with', 'within', 'without', 'would', 'yet',...
    'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'the'};

str1 = ('rabbit is eating grass near a tree and will be sleeping inside the tree-hole');
str2 = ('rabbit is sleeping under tree and after waking up will be eating the nuts nearby');

split1 = unique(regexp(str1,'\s','Split'),'stable');
split2 = unique(regexp(str2,'\s','Split'),'stable');

cw_split2 = split2(cell2_matchind(split1,split2))
cw_split2_nostopwd = cw_split2(~cell2_matchind(stopwords_cellstring,cw_split2))
cmp = numel(cw_split2_nostopwd)
```

Output -

```
cw_split2 = 
    'rabbit'    'is'    'sleeping'    'tree'    'and'    'will'    'be'    'eating'    'the'

cw_split2_nostopwd = 
    'rabbit'    'sleeping'    'tree'    'eating'

cmp =
     4
```

Comment: @user3416063 Read on few things to participate on stackoverflow - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 4):

As per the other answer split the string into a cell array of unique words.

```
str1= ('rabbit is eating grass near a tree');
str2= ('rabbit is sleeping under tree');

% split string into cell array of unique strings
split1 = regexp(str1,'\s','Split');
split2 = regexp(str2,'\s','Split');
```

Alternatively later versions of MATLAB (IIRC R2013a) includes a strsplit() function so the split could be reduced to

```
split1 = strsplit(str1);
split2 = strsplit(str2);
```

Then use the intersect() function to get the number of common elements between the two cell arrays. Add a length to return the integer count.

```
cmp = length(intersect(split1,split2));
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, really helpful. I googled a lot to find how to match particular words in a given string, but was not able to find any solution. It was really helpful.

Comment: +1 short and clear. I think `unique` is not necessary, as `intersect` automatically just considers unique values. As `ismember` does, compare with my example.

Comment: Thanks - you are right, unique isn't required. Makes it even simpler!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming there is no restriction on the location or order in which they are matching. First you need to split the sentence into individual words, remove any duplicates, and then see if any words in sentence two matches ones in the first sentence.

Now if ordering does matter, it is not quite as straightforward, but your question made no indication of such constraints

```
str1= ('rabbit is eating grass near a tree');
str2= ('rabbit is sleeping under tree');
split1 = unique(regexp(str1,'\s','Split'));
split2 = unique(regexp(str2,'\s','Split'));

% Storing all words in the first sentence into a map for quick search/access
dict = containers.Map();
for ii = 1:numel(split1)
   dict(split1{ii}) = true; 
end

% create temp holding cell array, then loop through, looking to see if 
% any word in the second sentence is stored in the dictionary made from
% the first sentence. 
matches = {};
for jj = 1:numel(split2)
    if dict.isKey(split2{jj})
        matches = [matches,split2{jj}]; % not best but length initially unknown
    end
end

numMatches = numel(matches) % return the number of matches
```

The variable `matches` will contain all of the words that match between the two sentences.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help, but i want an integer value to be returned, if 3 words are matching in above strings, then want output as 3, as it will help me in performing if-else condition, which will help me in my future work

Comment: @user3416063 seriously, you can just do a numel on that. but if you want me to add that sure, it is fixed. I ask you please do research on understanding the language before you post questions/comments that can be resolved very easily

Comment: Shouldn't need the complexity of maps and loops. The function intersect will return the common elements from two cell arrays of strings.

Comment: Thank you Sir, @ MZimmerman6, i am new to MATLAB, and their is no time for doing some research on MATLAB as their is a limited time for me to finish my work. In the future, will certainly do it.

Comment: @Adrian I forgot about the intersect function. This is the first thing I could think of, and is likely similar to what intersect does in the background. And also, should you want to do a similar thing in another language, this provides a very fast and simple solution that is performs in linear time.

Answer (score 2):

With `ismember` you just need one line.

```
str1 = ('rabbit is eating grass near a tree');
str2 = ('rabbit is sleeping under a tree');

result = sum( ismember( strsplit(str1), strsplit(str2) ) )

result =

    4               %// I included also the article "a"
```

**Be aware that for the following sentences the result is the same:**

```
str1 = ('rabbit is eating grass near a tree, an oak tree');
str2 = ('rabbit is sleeping under a tree and is dreaming about a tree');

result = sum( ismember( strsplit(str1), strsplit(str2) ) )
```

The removing of duplicates in advance, suggested by MZimmerman6 is not necessary.

---

If you want to filter the result for unwanted strings, you can introduce another cell array of strings with all exceptions:

```
str3 = {'is','a'}
unwanted = sum( ismember( intersect( strsplit(str1), strsplit(str2) ), str3 ) )

unwanted =

     2
```

---

**Alltogether it could look like:**

```
str1 = ('rabbit is eating grass near a tree, an oak tree');
str2 = ('rabbit is sleeping under a tree and is dreaming about a tree');
str3 = {'is','a'}

[x,y,z] = deal( strsplit(str1), strsplit(str2), str3 )
result = sum(ismember(x,y)) - sum(ismember(intersect(x,y),z))
       =       4            -            2           =        2
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, this was helpful, before it i was struggling how to use setdiff command for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for case insensitivity;

```
CMP = strcmpi(string,string)
```

Use this for case sensitivity;

```
CMP = strcmpi(string,string)
```

if CMP is 1 they are same if 0 they are not.

If you dont want to whitespaces, which makes better comparison please first trim them and compare.

For trimming;

```
newString = strtrim(str)
```

Comment: Won't this compare the entire string rather than the individual words?

Comment: It should compare entire string why not?

Comment: because they were after the count of matching words - not whether the entire string matches or not.