# Compare two strings and extract common word out

Tags: string, matlab, compare, extract

In MATLAB how can we compare 2 strings and print the common word out. For Example string1 = "hello my name is bob"; and string2 = "today bob went to the park";  the word bob is common in both. What is the structure to follow.

Comment: Have you tried something? Care to show us your code?

Comment: I am not sure. Till now I have worked some regexp to print out patterns.
like regexp(str,'[bob]'); to extract out particular word from a string but to compare two string and extract one common word may use logical operators
I think strfind or textscan may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html)** with **[`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)** for a one-liner -

```
common_word = intersect(strsplit(string1),strsplit(string2))
```

`strsplit` splits each string to cells of words and then `intersect` finds the common one out.

If you would like to avoid `strsplit`, you can use `regexp` instead -

```
common_word =intersect(regexp(string1,'\s','Split'),regexp(string2,'\s','Split'))
```

---

**Bonus: Removing stop-words from the common words**

Let's add some [**`stop-words`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) that are common to these two strings -

```
string1 = 'hello my name is bob and I am going to the zoo'
string2 = 'today bob went to the park'
```

Using the solution presented earlier, you would get -

```
common_word = 
    'bob'    'the'    'to'
```

Now, these words - `'the'` and `'to'` are part of the stop-words. If you would like to have them removed, let me suggest this - [**`Removing stop words from single string`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957584/removing-stop-words-from-single-string)
 and [it's accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22957934/3293881).

The final output would be `'bob'`, whom you were looking for!

Comment: One-liner will be efficient enough, but strsplit isn't a command for MATLAB. Let me try this as well.

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi See the edit for a `regexp` alternative!

Comment: @Divakar, Thanks for answering as well, intersect is a new command to me and looks very useful.

Comment: @Trogdor It is!! Let me suggest few more like that one - `ismember`, `setdiff`!

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi Check out the bonus part for removing stop-words too!

Comment: I don't know how this work. I am by all means a newbie here. Also seems we can't select two answers as accepted answers.
Alright, this stop-word is really helpful.

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi Yeah.. you can select only one as the accepted answer here. That's how it works here and the rest of the solutions get arranged according to the votes. There are few guidelines (not sure if they are official ones) [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @SamiyaQureshi - `strsplit` was only introduced into MATLAB as of R2013a.  The reason why it "isn't a command" for you is because you are using a version of MATLAB prior to R2013a.  Using `regexp` is the way to go to mimic what `strsplit` is doing. BTW +1 for you Divakar!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for matching words only, that are separated by spaces, you can use strsplit to change each string into cell arrays of words, then loop through and search for each one.

```
str1 = 'test if this works';
str2 = 'does this work?';
cell1 = strsplit(str1);
cell2 = strsplit(str2);
for n = 1:length(cell1)
    for m = 1:length(cell2)
    if strcmp(cell1{n},cell2{m})
        disp(cell1{n});
    end
    end
end
```

Notice that in my example the last member of cell2 is 'work?' so if you have punctuation in your strings, you'll have to do a check for that (isletter might help).

Comment: This could be done using regular expressions as well. `regexp(str,'\w+')` could be used instead of strsplit, and would help with punctuation problems.

Comment: I shall try this now and inform how it worked for me.

Comment: and yes it work out. Used regexp instead of strsplit.

Bests!! :)