# Getting unnecessary stop words from text in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
stopwords_cellstring={'a','s', 'about', 'above', 'above', 'across', 'after', ...
'afterwards', 'again', 'against', 'all', 'almost', 'alone', 'along', ...
'already', 'also','although','always','am','among', 'amongst', 'amoungst', ...
'amount',  'an', 'and', 'another', 'any','anyhow','anyone','anything','anyway', ...
'anywhere', 'are', 'around', 'as',  'at', 'back','be','became', 'because','become',...
'becomes', 'becoming', 'been', 'before', 'beforehand', 'behind', 'being', 'below',...
'beside', 'besides', 'between', 'beyond', 'bill','all','When', 'both', 'bottom','but', 'by',...
'call', 'can', 'cannot', 'cant', 'co', 'con', 'could', 'couldnt', 'cry', 'de',...
'describe', 'detail', 'do', 'done', 'down', 'due', 'during', 'each', 'eg', 'eight',...
'either', 'eleven','else', 'elsewhere', 'empty', 'enough', 'etc', 'even', 'ever', ...
'every', 'everyone', 'everything', 'everywhere', 'except', 'few', 'fifteen', 'fify',...
'fill', 'find', 'fire', 'first', 'five', 'for', 'former', 'formerly', 'forty', 'found',...
'four', 'from', 'front', 'full', 'further', 'get', 'give', 'go', 'had', 'has', 'hasnt',...
'have', 'he', 'hence', 'her', 'here', 'hereafter', 'hereby', 'herein', 'hereupon', ...
'hers', 'herself', 'him', 'himself', 'his', 'how', 'however', 'hundred', 'ie', 'if',...
'in', 'inc', 'indeed', 'interest', 'into', 'is', 'it', 'its', 'itself', 'keep', 'last',...
'latter', 'latterly', 'least', 'less', 'ltd', 'made', 'many', 'may', 'me', 'meanwhile',...
'might', 'mill', 'mine', 'more', 'moreover', 'most', 'mostly', 'move', 'much', 'must',...
'my', 'myself', 'name', 'namely', 'neither', 'never', 'nevertheless', 'next', 'nine',...
'no', 'nobody', 'none', 'noone', 'nor', 'not', 'nothing', 'now', 'nowhere', 'of', 'off',...
'often', 'on', 'once', 'one', 'only', 'onto', 'or', 'other', 'others', 'otherwise',...
'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'out', 'over', 'own','part', 'per', 'perhaps', 'please',...
'put', 'rather', 're', 'same', 'see', 'seem', 'seemed', 'seeming', 'seems', 'serious',...
'several', 'she', 'should', 'show', 'side', 'since', 'sincere', 'six', 'sixty', 'so',...
'some', 'somehow', 'someone', 'something', 'sometime', 'sometimes', 'somewhere', ...
'still', 'such', 'system', 'take', 'ten', 'than', 'that', 'the', 'their', 'them',...
'themselves', 'then', 'thence', 'there', 'thereafter', 'thereby', 'therefore', ...
'therein', 'thereupon', 'these', 'they', 'thickv', 'thin', 'third', 'this', 'those',...
'though', 'three', 'through', 'throughout', 'thru', 'thus', 'to', 'together', 'too',...
'top', 'toward', 'towards', 'twelve', 'twenty', 'two', 'un', 'under', 'until', 'up',...
'upon', 'us', 'very', 'via', 'was', 'we','all', 'well', 'were','uses','way','went', 'what', 'whatever', 'when',...
'whence', 'whenever', 'where', 'whereafter', 'whereas', 'whereby', 'wherein',...
'whereupon', 'wherever', 'whether', 'which', 'while', 'whither', 'who', 'whoever',...
'whole','When', 'whom', 'whose','saw', 'why', 'will', 'with', 'within', 'without', 'would', 'yet',...
'you', 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'the'};
```

above are the stop words that i am using to process a text file and removing them but there are some words which are not still eliminated listed as follows:

```
[3]    'The'

[6]    'â'

[5]    's'
```

can anyone help me how to eliminate these words the code i'm using is as follows

```
str1 = F
split1 = regexp(str1,'\s','Split');
out_str1 = strjoin(split1(~ismember(split1,stopwords_cellstring)),' ')
C = regexp(out_str1, '<s>|\w*|</s>', 'match');
```

Comment: Use `regexpi` (case insensitive) instead?

Comment: @Divakar Tried it but didn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing stop words from single string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957584/removing-stop-words-from-single-string)

Answer (score 0):

Just concentrating on word filtering and if willing to be case insensitive, using `~ismember` will not work. Here is a solution to filter *stopwords* while being not case sensitive:

```
str1 = F
split1 = regexp(str1,'\s','Split');

%%%%
logic = arrayfun(@(word)any(strcmpi(word, stopwords_cellstring)), split1);
out_str1 = strjoin(split1(~logic), ' ');    
%%%%


C = regexp(out_str1, '<s>|\w*|</s>', 'match');
```

**How it works:**

I have replaced `ismember` test with `arrayfun`. For each *word* in `split1`, the `arrayfun` checks if this *word* match any of the words in `stopwords_cellstring` using `strcmpi` (case insensitive).

NB1: For `s` it is not part of your stop list.

NB2: For `â`, I don't know if there's a quick solution to convert it to `a` (i.e without accentuation) ... easy solution would be to add it to your list unless it is included in more complex word like *âmer* for instance ... in this last case I would advice you to prefilter `str1` with `str1 = strrep(str1, 'â', 'a')`.

Comment: thanks mate, the case sensitivity issue is solved and 'The' is removed but 'a' is part of my list as u can see in question it is still shown in the output. is there any way to correctly insert 'a' in the stop words list.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad As indicated in my `NB2`, prefilter `str1` with `str1 = strrep(str1, 'â', 'a');` ... or, if still not what you want, provide us with a simple string where filtering is not ok.

Comment: actually i am finding word frequencies from the text file, may be the issue is the code is not reading single character like 'a' and 's' as stop words although they are present in the stop word list, may be there exist some other method for reading single characters and omitting them.